# With react-router, redux will not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux, redux-thunk

I have read lots of similar questions，And no one fit for me.

about

[this.props.children doesn't always inherit the context from its parent](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5507)

[Could not find "store" in either the context or props](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/issues/57)

```
//store config
const createHistoryWithBasename = (historyOptions) => {
    return useBasename(createHistory)({
        basename: '/user_home'
    })
}
const finalCreateStore = compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk, createLogger()),
    reduxReactRouter({
        createHistory: createHistoryWithBasename }),
        devTools()
    )(createStore);

export function configureStore(initialState) {
    const store = finalCreateStore(rootReducer, initialState);
    return store;
}
```

the index file, all route nested in Provider.

```
//entry file
let routes = (
    <Route path="/" component={UserHome}></Route>
);

ReactDom.render(
    <Provider store={store} >
        <ReduxRouter>
            {routes}
        </ReduxRouter>
    </Provider>,
    rootElement
);
```

the Component. I logged the *this.props*, there are't the *dispatch* property. And the parameter of *context* is an empty object.

```
//user_home.js
class UserHome extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context){
        //context is empty Object
        super(props, context);
    }
    render() {
        //this.props.dispatch is undefined
        return (
            <div className="container">
               test
            </div>
        );
    }

}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return state;
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    pushState
})(UserHome);
```

Maybe, it's a simple question, but It took me a lot of time.Hope to get your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we can inject the action creator to *connect*

```
import * as ActionCreators from './actions/user_actions';

//we can use the actions in ActionCreators to dispatch the action.

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    pushState: pushState,
    ...ActionCreators
})(Component);
```

the actions

```
//action file
export function xxAction(){
    return dispatch =>{
        dispatch({
            type: 'XX_ACTION'
        });
    }
}
```

this solution fit for dispatching actions in children component.There are some limitations, Looking forward to a better solution.

Comment: Hello where. Basically, for your approach you'll need to use `redux-thunk` to pass dispatch to action creator, which seems like overkill for simple situation. You have `mapDispatchToProps` function as second `connect` parameter, and it's designed to bind action-creators to `dispatch` and to pass them further to props of connected component.

Speaking on `context`, your component wouldn't have an access to it unless you specify `contextTypes` field on your child component.